# Tabris Example Android Bug?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a question about the Android Tutorial (Getting started with Tabris on Android ) from the Tabris Website.

When I start the Tabris App within the android emulator from eclipse I became the following message "Discovery Failed".

I saw that the Tabris App from the tutorial use the url http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/

Open this url in a normal browser that result in a tomcat error.

Is it possible that the url http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/ is invalid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL you have mentioned is not Tabris demo Android url, but the Rich Ajax Platform demo (http://eclipse.org/rap/)
For Tabris online demo's you need to visit: http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/demos/

I guess you are mixing up two different projects ;)

If you want to run the Tabris demo on your own local machine, follow the instructions given : http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/getting-started-with-android-sdk/

Comment: I download the SDK from the URL http://developer.eclipsesource.com/technology/tabris/downloads/0.6/sdk/Tabris-0.6.1-SDK.zip there is in zip-File tabris-android-0.6.1.zip the launcher.properties file and this file contains the url url=http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/ and I am not sure that this url is valid. I use the android emulator within eclipse

Comment: I think the url is not ok. It might be that url will work once you get the application server running, android application deployed, and you refer to localhost instead of rap.eclipsesource.com. Did you drop the guys from Tabris an email?

Answer (score 2):

The URL http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/ is correct. This is where the Tabris/RAP Application with the client demos is deployed.

The important part are the entry points!

So there are two ways to configure your Client:

1. Point it to http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/ (dont't forget the `/` at the end!) and the client will discover all available entry points by accessing http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/index.json
2. Point your client to exactly one entry point: http://rap.eclipsesource.com/demos-0.6.0/simple-tree